# SELECT from Collection denies to accept to_number/to_char

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

refering to my other post i decided to store numbers with leading zero in my database.
I'm selecting the imported data from a collection and insert it into a database table. The problem is that if I try to use the function to_char(c001,'009') on a column out of the collection it says "ORA-01722: invalid number".

I don't understand this because the datasource is varchar2 and the destination is varchar2, too.

Did anyone solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's to_char function takes a number as it's first parameter. So the value you provide will be converted to number. If coo1 does not contain a valid number you will get that error message.

One of you numbers is not a number. You can use plsql code to find out what record contains an invalid number:

```
declare
  l_number number;
  cursor c is select ID,column_name from table;
begin
  for r in c loop
    begin
      l_number := to_number(r.column_name);
    exception
      when others then dbms_output.put_line(r.id||' '||r.column_name);
    end;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thats what I assumed. But the data in those colums are (as far as i can see) numbers. If I write this data into the table it works like a charm and they are numbers.

Comment: So what if you select to_char(column_name,'009') from that table?

Comment: that's what i'm doing. This is the reason for this ORA.

Comment: Thought you were selecting the contents of a collection. You've placed the varchar2 contents into a varchar2 column. How can you be sure all of them are indeed numbers? Are they integers? You could have a decimal , or . problem. Try select to_number(column_name) from table.

Comment: yes indeed i'm selecting data from the collection inside of an insert into another table. The data is integer in any case. the to_number() function causes the same issue than to_char.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I think I didn't recognize that indeed the first row in my collection is the header of the xls file and thats no number. I think i have to remove the first element of this collection to get it work.